# How to get articles by category in Strapi CMS

Tags: strapi

```
http://localhost:1337/posts?_where[categories]=<catId>_sort=createdAt:DESC&_start=0&_limit=3
```

Used the above API pattern to filter posts by categories but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to get this work.
Posts has and belongs to many Categories

Answer (score 7):

It's not a big problem. Just go strapi cms panel choose articles in content manager and use filter button to filtering articles by category. When strapi do this check address bar in browser and copy last part with filter to your request. that's all.

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is a great solution. I had never thought about trying to figure things out this way, it actually works really well.

Comment: this is great way to make query, i am going to edit you answer and add images screenshot in post

Answer (score 3):

with Strapi v4 i was able to filter my products by category like so:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/products?filters[$and][0][category][category][$eq]={categoryName}
```

And this with Images included

```
http://localhost:1337/api/products?filters[$and][0][category][category][$eq]={categoryName}&populate=*
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.0.3
Try this: http://localhost:1337/api/posts?filters[category][catID][$eq]=2

This worked for me.

V 4.0 Deep Filtering Docs:
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#deep-filtering

Comment: I've made a category content type and made a many-to-many relation between that and my posts. then specified category for my posts and tried query that you've typed but id didn't work!
error : {"data":null,"error":{"status":500,"name":"InternalServerError","message":"Internal Server Error"}}
my query : http://localhost:4001/api/posts?filters[category][catID][$eq]=2

Answer (score 0):

1.create Enumeration name  = type
2.create your items in Enumeration

```
** [filters][enumeraton name]
** ${type} = your props type
```

```
http://localhost:1337//products?populate=*&[filters][type][$eq]=${type}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [@Blue_Abe1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15392841/blue-abe1)'s answer, I would like to share how I solved this using [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs), which is Strapi's way of creating complex queries:

```
import qs from 'qs';

const queryParams = {
  filters: {
    categories: {
      name: {
        $eq: 'food'
      }
    }
  }
};

const queryString = qs.stringify(queryParams);
const articles = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/articles?${queryString}`)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
http://localhost:1337/posts?_where[categories.name]=ACL&_sort=createdAt:DESC&_start=0&_limit=3
```

That is how it is done. We can replace name with id or any other properties

Comment: did not work in v4.0.0